# Django queryset searching for firstname and lastname with startswith

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

I have one django app, In which I search for a name from first_name and last_name.
Which is working for me using Q tag.

```
from django.db.models import Q 

def find_user_by_name(query_name):
   qs = User.objects.all()
   for term in query_name.split():
     qs = qs.filter( Q(first_name__icontains = term) | Q(last_name__icontains = term))
   return qs
```

But I'm facing one issue regarding ordering the data not coming as I want.

**For example**: search_word = 'Kia'
The result I got after the search is:

```
        {
            "first_name": "Katja",
            "last_name": "Tukiainen", 
        },
        {
            "first_name": "Kia",
            "last_name": "Reijonen",
        },
        {
            "first_name": "Sanna",
            "last_name": "Kiander",
        }
    ]
```

But I want a result in which first starts with **Kia** first, Result like:

```
        {
            "first_name": "Kia",
            "last_name": "Reijonen",
        },
        {
            "first_name": "Katja",
            "last_name": "Tukiainen",
            
        },
        {
            "first_name": "Sanna",
            "last_name": "Kiander",
        }
    ]
```

Please help me regarding this, I try this with **startswith** but not working for me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with an [**`.union(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#union):

```
def find_user_by_name(query_name):
    qs = User.objects.all()
    q1 = Q(*[
        Q(('first_name__istartswith', term)) | Q(('last_name__istartswith', term))
        for term in query_name.split()
    ])
    q2 = Q(*[
        Q(('first_name__icontains', term)) | Q(('last_name__icontains', term))
        for term in query_name.split()
    ])
    return qs.filter(q1).union(qs.filter(q2))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering me but it will give an error of ValueError.
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: @AbhishekDubey: there was a pair of parenthesis missing.

Comment: Can we add two fields with startswith?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70751460/django-queryset-multiple-fields-seaching-with-startwith

Answer (score 0):

first you'll have to RND on django full text search but for now try this.

Add

"django.contrib.postgres",

to your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

then use the following search vector and Search Rank

```
    vector = SearchVector('first_name', weight='A') + SearchVector('last_name', weight='B')
    query = SearchQuery('Kia')
    users =User.objects.annotate(rank=SearchRank(vector, query)). \
        filter(Q(last_name__icontains='Kia') | Q(first_name__icontains='Kia')).order_by('-rank')
```

Remember to import

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchQuery, SearchRank, SearchVector
```

Good luck!