# Django queryset multiple fields seaching with startwith

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views, union

Can we add **startswith** with multiple fields? With one field it will work fine for me but with multiple fields, it gives an error to me.

```
def find_user_by_name_location():
    qs = User.objects.all()
    query_name = request.POST.get('name')
    location = request.POST.get('location')


    if query_name:
        q1 = Q(*[
            Q(('first_name__istartswith', term)) | Q(('last_name__istartswith', term))
            for term in query_name.split()
        ])
        q2 = Q(*[
            Q(('first_name__icontains', term)) | Q(('last_name__icontains', term))
            for term in query_name.split()
        ])
        qs = qs.filter(q1).union(qs.filter(q2))

    if location:
        q1 = Q(town__istartswith=location)
        q2 = Q(town__icontains=location) | Q(post_code__icontains=location) | Q(post_area__icontains=location) | Q(street__icontains=location) | Q(country__icontains=location) | Q(agency__operating_areas__icontains=location)
        
        qs = qs.filter(q1).union(qs.filter(q2))

    return qs.all()
```

**For Example**: We search with both(location and name) then it will give first priority to **first_name** from name and **town** from location searching.

```
{
    "first_name": "Katja",
    "last_name": "Tukiainen",
    "town" : "Helsinki",
    "country": "Helsinki",
},
{
    "first_name": "Kia",
    "last_name": "Reijonen",
    "town": "Espoo",
    "country": "Helsinki",
},
{
    "first_name": "Sanna",
    "last_name": "Kiander",
    "town": "Helsinki",
    "country": "Espoo",
}
```

If we search with both then. it will give me a union-related error, Please suggest me better way to search with multiple fields using startswith or another way to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a much simpler version of the query that still shows the problem.  You are asking for help with searching, but then you are describing an error with the `.union` call.  What is that error?  It doesn't seem to be related to the search.

Comment: @Andrew I searched on multiple fields for names I am searching on first_name and last_name  but give first priority to first_name. Same way for the location I give first priority to the town field it works fine for me using union.
But when I am using both in searching then it gives an error-related union.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70001213/django-queryset-searching-for-firstname-and-lastname-with-startswith

Comment: Try to reproduce this with a much simpler example and post that.  Start with name & location set to the values you have when you get the issue, and then simplify it until you don't get the issue anymore. Right now you have TWO unions but you don't say which one is crashing, and you are asking for debugging help with lots of research.  Simplify, then post the line that fails AND the error message you get.